# Should I use "Map" or "Select" for new functor-like operators in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm designing a type in C# that will be used as an algebraic type in a functional style, but is not a collection type and does not implement `IEnumerable`.  If this type is a Functor, should I name its projection method `Select` or `Map`?  Similarly, if it's Filterable, should I name that method `Filter` or `Where`?  What are the pros and cons of following LINQ's naming convention vs. matching the larger functional community?

For concrete examples, consider things like `Optional<T>` and `IObservable<T>`.

Considerations:

- If we choose `Select` over `Map`, what happens when the type also fits other common algebraic structures like Contravariant?  Do we keep `Contramap` and accept the mismatch with `Select`?  Do we make up names like `ContraSelect`?
- If we choose `Map` over `Select`, how "collection-like" can our type get before we're more or less in direct conflict with LINQ?
- Following LINQ names allows for query syntax support, but do we want to encourage or discourage query syntax for types that are very unlike `IQueryable`?

Comment: The gist of your question can be grokked by simply reading the title.  Ultimately, this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I suppose if someone wants to downvote a question immediately, without comment, based on "the gist", there's nothing I can do to stop them, but that person is certainly a detriment to this site.

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  Voting on Stack Exchange is anonymous by design, and after reading your question, the title covered my understanding with about 95 percent accuracy.  I've actually thought about your question before, and concluded that there's no right or wrong answer.  Like many language features, it's a matter of personal taste (for better or worse).

Comment: Does that make it a bad question? If there was an obvious right or wrong answer, why would I bother asking? Is this not the right site for posing interesting software engineering questions?

Comment: Yes, but we prefer answering questions factually.

Comment: "This is a matter of opinion" is a great answer to a question. Honestly, matters of opinions should be almost obvious or fully documented as being analogous in the docs, and if they aren't either of the two, then this is a valid question to be asked. I suppose I should also weigh in -- I think LINQ was created with databases and SQL in mind so it would make sense for the library to use familiar SQL syntax like 'select' and 'where'.